# Subgroups of the integers mod n

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have the following 2 questions:

1. What are the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$?
2. Why are $\{[0]\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ the only subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$?

For 1, I'm not sure whether the answer is $\{[0]\}$, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, and $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ (aren't $\{[0]\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ the same?), or if it's all $\{[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]\}$. Could someone provide some clarity on this? I'm not sure I even know what these mean.

For 2, I'm thinking because 7 is prime, its only divisors are 1 and itself, 7, so its only subgroups are the groups that divide it. If this is the case, then for question 1, it would make sense that my first guess was right, but I feel like I've seen $\{[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]\}$ as the subgroups for the integers mod 6 before.

Comment: $\{[0]\}$ is $\mathbb{Z}/1\mathbb{Z}$ and has 1 element, $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ has 6 elements, definitely not the same. What do you mean by 'is it all of $\{[0],...,[5]\}$', that this is the only subgroup?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: ${\bf Z}/2{\bf Z}$ is **not** a subgroup of ${\bf Z}/6{\bf Z}$, but ${\bf Z}/6{\bf Z}$ does have a subgroup **isomorphic** to ${\bf Z}/2{\bf Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you misunderstood the concept of subgroups. Therefore, you should definitely  check the definition again. But as a short input for you to think about:

**1:** $\{[0]\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. Why? If you add $[0]+[0]$ you get $[0]$. That means that this set is closed under addition, you have a neutral element and an inverse for every element because you only have that one element which satisfies the conditions for a subgroup. Now check the same conditions for every other set. For example: $\{[0],[2],[4]\}$ or $\{[0],[1],[3],[5]\}$. (Hint: One of them is the other is not a subgroup)

**2:** You already have the right intuition. However the phrase

> because 7 is prime, its only divisors are 1 and itself, 7, so its only subgroups are the groups that divide it

seems a bit odd. A subgroup cannot really divide any number. A subgroup is a subset of another group with an operation. The elements inside that subgroup however can. And that is the answer you are looking for. When talking about $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ the subgroups are those sets whose elements are every multiple of those which divide $n$. In the case of $7$ that is $\{[7]\}=\{[0]\}$ and $\{[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]\}$.